# C# NTLM authentication function

Tags: c#, .net, ntlm-authentication

I need to programmatically rewrite NTLM authentication over http.

.Net does it by simple code like this:

```
public static byte [] downloadFile(string url){
  using (var client = new WebClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain") })
      {
           return client.DownloadData(url);
      }   }
```

But I want to modify NTLM over http that .Net implements and write a new class inherent by WebClient.

So which class in .Net implements NTLM over http or how .Net handle NTLM authentication?

Comment: Can you explain more about your requirements / needs?

Comment: Which class in .Net is responsible for NTLM Authentication in the back-end?

Comment: @Robotech_Life - It depends which back-end you use... you showed client code....

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_NtlmClient.cs,b300f9eab02ba4c8

Comment: P.S. you probably do not want to rewrite an NTLM implementation...

Comment: I found a Microsoft sample that does it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.authenticationmanager?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples

Answer (score 0):

[SSPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/sspi) does it all for you.  If you want to roll your [own NTLM](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html), there is a lot of work to be done. What is SSPI not doing for you?